# App rejected on 4.2 Design: Minimum Functionality with Flutter app

Tags: appstore-approval

I complete my app and publish it to google play
but when published to the app store. I facing this message from apple.

```
App rejected on 4.2 Design: Minimum Functionality
```

and I afraid apple rejected my app because it made by Flutter, not Xcode.

note: My app includes GPS, notification, Facebook login, Facebook like, send message

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because appstore-approval related questions are off-topic as per the tag description

Comment: I disagree with you @Scriptable, its helpful

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris the description of the tag is "App store approval is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions marked with this tag concern the approval process of an iOS or OS X application by Apple before the application is added to the App Store. If this applies to your question, it is very likely off-topic."

Answer (score 3):

Our app was finally released by Apple after several attemps. Here is what we changed to get the app accepted:

- We added an exact description of the app functionality in English.
- We wrote a text addressing the review team to explain how the users can benefit from the app and what is the intention of the company publishing the app.
- We made a screenshot showing the Apple maps integration of the app.

I hope this can help you to get your app accepted.

Comment: Hello I am still facing issue. What do you mean by added exact description? How does it going to be map with native functionality?

Answer (score 0):

As Luis Miguel Mantilla mentioned, you could start by checking out the guidelines — [App Store Review Guidelines: 4.2 Minimum Functionality](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#design) — pointed out be the person who rejected you.

Rejection of an app is extremely common with Apple, because the are very strict, bureaucratic and inflexible, in an attempt of trying to maintain a high quality app store. Even with big apps, it's very common for people to face many rejections before managing to get a build in.

Their strictness also causes their reviewers to either be imobile or seem dumb. For example, in a first app I tried to build, I had implemented a basic login initial screen; and, because they have guidelines for the reviewers about the login, the reviewer simply didn't do anything and rejected my app — I think I had to necessarily provide test users —, even though he could have simple created a dummy test user by himself — I had informed so in the build description.

Another way of solving your rejection problem is by contacting your reviewer directly. When your build is rejected, you will receive an email like this:

> Dear `<your_name>`,
>
> Your app, `<app_name_and_build>`, has been reviewed, but cannot be made
>   available for TestFlight beta testing.
>
> For details, or to contact App Store Review, visit **Resolution
>   Center** in App Store Connect.
>
> Best regards, App Store Review

By clicking on the `Resolution Center` link, you will be able to talk to the person and poke out what's really going on, instead of having to suffer from anxiety by endlessly speculating over it.

Lastly, [this article](https://www.mobiloud.com/blog/avoid-app-rejected-apple/) was somewhat useful when I was first rejected.

Answer (score -1):

It's a good idea to read the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) before send an App to the App Store, but as a developers sometimes we forgot it. What I can suggest you, because once I have a similar rejected case but in other field, is to check each term in the section [4.2 Minimum Functionality](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#design) in the guidelines. Another thing is that you can send an email, requesting more information about the rejection, but that you have made your app with Flutter, absolutely is not the problem.

Comment: Am uploaded to appstore using material desgin . I thing to change to cupertino desgin